# How can I start over on my site?

Tags: customization

I would like to zero out my site and begin over. How can I do that?

I have two home page and I only want one, which will be the Front page and will be static. I'm not even sure if this is possible.

I may put a Blog on another page - later. Right now I just want a web site.

I know that people have made good web sites on WordPress but I find it extremely difficult and just get stuck with no where to go, no search box, no ability to use WordPress forums. I got a little help here but not enough.

Comment: Is there anything you need other than the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set which one page is blog page and which one is front page you need to go in administration to the Settings - Reading and there switch "Front page displays" to the "A static page" and below choose the pages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all your WordPress website content why not install a new one?

Otherwise, you can install a plugin like this one: [Bulk Delete](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-delete/) where you can delete posts, pages and other elements of the website in bulk.